# SQL Server: preventing manual insert into a column controlled by a sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sequence

I have a `Sequence` object set on one of our databases with an increment of 1, that we are currently using as the primary key for two of our tables to ensure uniqueness across them both. This is controlled via the following constraint on the tables:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT SEQ_MySequence DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ_sID) FOR ID;
```

We want to prevent a user from manually inserting data into this column, but we cannot find a reliable method to do so. A trigger seems like the obvious choice; however AFTER INSERT triggers execute after constraints are fired and thus the below does not work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BlockInsert ON MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
   IF (SELECT ID FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
       ROLLBACK
END
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you Googled the other types of triggers?

Comment: Remove insert permissions on the table and enforce that all inserts and updates must go through a view that does not expose that column?

Comment: Would you consider using an `Identity column` instead ?

Comment: Or restrict user access so that they must execute stored procedures that you provide which handle the transactions appropriately?

Comment: You could use an INSTEAD OF trigger. I would urge you to something better than just quietly issuing a rollback. You should raise an error so it is obvious something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence main goal is only to ensure uniqueness across the two tables, then consider using odd and even identity columns on the tables.
Example Table A will have an identity seed of 1 with an increment of 2 (odd) and Table B will have an identity seed of 2 with an increment of 2 (even).  If there is a chance that IDENTITY_INSERT can be used, then you will also have to add some additional check constraints to ensure correct behavior.
Example Use:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA 
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY ( 1 , 2 ) CONSTRAINT PK_Odd PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
    Data varchar(10)
) 

-- Check constraint ensures ID is always odd
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD CONSTRAINT
CK_ODD_ID CHECK ( ID % 2 = 1 )


CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY ( 2 , 2 ) CONSTRAINT PK_Even PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
    Data varchar(10)
) 
-- Check constraint ensures ID is always even
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD CONSTRAINT
CK_EVEN_ID CHECK ( ID % 2 = 0 )
```

This approach simplifies the database design by avoiding the use of triggers and sequences. If uniqueness maybe required over more than two tables sometime in the future, then I would avoid this method all together.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. If more tables are required in future, the identities can be altered with alter column. E.g. `ALTER TABLE TableA ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (10001, 4)` and `ALTER TABLE TableA ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (10002, 4)` and so forth.

Comment: @Ben - Except there is no such syntax. The only way of doing it as a metadata only change would be `ALTER TABLE .. SWITCH`

Comment: A simple and innovative solution. However, we may want this value to be unique over a third table in future, and, as you pointed out at the bottom of your answer, this method won't work. Many thanks for your input, however!

Comment: @SeeBeeEss - No worries, your solution involving the triggers will definitely be your best option then.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your suggestions. I came up with the below solution using an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger which I feel mimics the behavior of an identity column quite well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BlockInsert ON MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    IF (SELECT ID FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL
        THROW 50000, 'Explict insert into column "ID" is forbidden', 1
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO MyTable ([ID],[ColumnA],[ColumnB])
        SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MySequenceObject,[ColumnA],[ColumnB]
        FROM inserted
END
```

This checks if the ID value the user is trying to insert is an actual value instead of NULL. If so, the insert is aborted and an error is thrown. If not, row is inserted using the next value of the Sequence as the ID column.

Since INSTEAD OF Triggers occur before any table constraints, it doesn't break the NOT NULL constraint of the column, and also occurs before the row to be inserted has been assigned an ID from the sequence.

This way, a user will never be able to insert their own value into the ID column – it  must come from the sequence object - which is what we want.

Updates can also be handled using the below trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BlockUpdate ON MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE ([ID])
        THROW 50000, 'Update of column "ID" is forbidden', 1
        ROLLBACK
END
```